# CoreOS 1353.4.0 - How should I configure Ignition for an etcd cluster member with dynamic discovery?

Tags: coreos, etcd, coreos-ignition

Using CoreOS 1353.4.0, on DigitalOcean, how should I write an Ignition config for a machine that is to join an etcd cluster with dynamic discovery?

I've written the following Ignition config (basically in keeping with [this guide](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/op-guide/clustering.html#etcd-discovery)), but there seems to be problems with it as I cannot SSH into machines configured with it, nor can I ping them:

```
etcd:
  advertise_client_urls: http://{PRIVATE_IPV4}:2379
  discovery: https://discovery.etcd.io/715ba22c9924d4edd7aa674eeefddf87
  initial_advertise_peer_urls: http://{PRIVATE_IPV4}:2380
  listen_client_urls: http://0.0.0.0:2379
  listen_peer_urls: http://{PRIVATE_IPV4}:2380
  name: '{HOSTNAME}'
```

This configuration file is turned into native Ignition syntax by executing the CoreOS [configuration transpiler](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/overview-of-ct.html): `ct -in-file config.yaml -out-file config.ign -platform digitalocean`.

I suspect the configuration is to blame, as there are some warnings during the machines' bootup. Droplet created without any config function fine, meaning I can ping and SSH into them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this actually works well. I was simply making a mistake when posting the config to the DigitalOcean API that caused the syntax to become invalid.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the mistake? I'm coming up with the same error.

Comment: @BelminFernandez Can't remember at this stage, sorry :/